# Which versions of ubuntu are compatible with INTEL Core i5 6th generation ASUS A556U laptop

Tags: 14.04

I had ubuntu 14.04 on my lap but it did not support my trackpad. I am very new to OS and compatibility issues. Please help me out

Comment: All of them. You haven't given any details, nor can we accurately predict whether or not Ubuntu will work. 16.04 was just released today, so you could try that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This was a kernel bug which was fixed in Ubuntu 15.10, so 15.10 and later should be OK